# Installing ipa on device not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, installation, ipa

I have a problem installing an ipa via `diawi.com`. It says that it is unable to install it.

It was working fine before, until one morning when Xcode said that it cannot find the provisioning profile on my mac.
So I generated another ad hoc distribution profile (with the same app id, and included the device UDID).
I installed it manually in Xcode and set the Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile fields in the `BuildSettings->CodeSigning` in both PROJECT and TARGETS.
I even tried sync-ing the apple account profiles with Xcode and i get the same result.

Also, old uploaded ipa-s on diawi still work (so it's not something they changed).

Using `Xcode 5.1` (58130a)
Trying to install it on an iPhone 4S with iOS 7.0.
The Deployment Target and iOS SDK fields in Build Settings are set to iOS 7.1

Comment: have you tried setting the Deployment Target to 6.0?

Comment: yeah ... as i found out ... if i updated the iOS version to 7.1 it works ... do i have to change some settings in order for it to work on under iOS 7.1? ... Also, should i worry about this when uploading the app for App Store Review? ... thanks